# calling stopForeground leads to restart the current service

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I started a foreground service with a notification id however when i try to call `stopForeground(false)` the service is getting restarted. But according to the android docs calling this method does not stop the service.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
      LogHelper.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        super.onCreate();
        initMediaSeesion();
    }

@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent startIntent, int flags, int startId) {
        LogHelper.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(mSession, startIntent);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void startNotification() {
            if (!mStarted) {
                Notification notification = createNotification();
                if (notification != null) {
                    mService.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
                    mStarted = true;
                }
            }
        }

    @Override
        public void pause() {
            LogHelper.d(TAG, "Calling stopForeground false");
            giveUpAudioFocus();
            mService.stopForeground(false);
    }
```

Logs:

```
03-25 08:50:40.200 19564-19564/? D/MusicService: Calling stopForeground false
03-25 08:50:40.352 19564-19564/? D/MusicService: onCreate
03-25 08:50:40.475 19564-19564/? D/MusicService: onStartCommand
03-25 08:50:40.476 19564-19564/? D/MusicService: onStartCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you set START_STICKY when you stop the service it automatically restart.

This is what Android DOC says

> For started services, there are two additional major modes of operation they can decide to run in, depending on the value they return from onStartCommand(): START_STICKY is used for services that are explicitly started and stopped as needed, while START_NOT_STICKY or START_REDELIVER_INTENT are used for services that should only remain running while processing any commands sent to them. See the linked documentation for more detail on the semantics.

Try using stopSelf();